# Pandas - Reading CSV file with field contents grouped in different cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import a CSV into Jupyter Notebooks in order to analyze the data.

Since the fields are separated by a '|' character, I use the following to import the data:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.read_csv('/filename.csv', sep='|')
```

The headers are imported correctly, but the data is not. There is a group of fields in the first column (still separated by the `|` character.) If I open the CSV file in Excel, I see that all column names are in the first cell and separated by `|`, but the data is different. There is a group of fields in the first cell with the same separator, then a group of fields in the second one, etc.

Basically it looks like this:

```
    Row 1: (First cell) Column A name | Column B name... 

    Row 2 (first cell) Field A | Field B | Field C    (second cell) Field D | Field E ....
```

I imagine this can be solved by using different options with read_csv.

Comment: what does the data look like in a `.txt` file (opened with something like notepad)? There may be a funky character in the file that is causing the separator to be misinterpreted.

Comment: @MattR - It looks like it is splitting the fields when it finds a comma (some of the fields contain strings that have commas in them.) Is there any way I can tell Pandas to ignore those? The field separator is | and the end of line marks the start of a new record. Thank you!

Comment: What's the desired final format? do you want to split those fields into new columns or keep them as-is ?

Comment: @QusaiAlothman - I would like to split those fields into new columns. It seems that the separator is being misinterpreted because some of the fields contain strings with commas. I have tried using pd.read_csv('/filename.csv', sep='|', quotechar='"') but it doesn't seem to work. Looking into a solution right now...

Comment: ok, there is a simple solution for that. But I have another question: Are you sure that the number of fields in each row is constant? Or there may be rows with unknown/variable number of fields?

Comment: @QusaiAlothman - The number of fields is constant. Unknown values are entered as NULL.

Comment: OK, it is working now. I just needed to change the order: 
pd.read_csv('/filename.csv', quotechar='"', sep='|') Thanks for all the help!

Comment: what do you mean by "order"? the order of the arguments?

Comment: That's correct. And my apologies, I was editing my original comments to add the final code but you were too fast! :) Thanks again!

Comment: Also, @MattR - Your first comment was what helped me find the solution, so thanks again!

Comment: @Irina, no problem. These are basic things in the life of a Data Analyst that you just pick up. You'll start to learn these "did you turn it on/off again" type of IT questions with data. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options in [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

As figured out by the comments, the root cause of this is normally a "funky character". In your case, it was a text-qualified comma. Other times, users may run into a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) causing the bad ouput, another special ASCII symbol, or [simply Excel displaying the character as a number](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/code.php). You can solve your issue in Excel when you delimit the file using a text qualifier by:

`Data Tab -> Text to Columns -> Delimited -> Set Text Qualifier`. See below:
[image]

To solve this in pandas you can try `pd.read_csv('/filename.csv', quotechar='"', sep='|')`. According to your comments, it is important that `quoutechar=` comes before `sep=`. Alternatively you can use `delimiter=` instead of `sep`. as in the docs delimiter is just:

> Alternative argument name for sep.